# Comparing attributes of current element and different elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery

I am trying to compare an attribute of a current element in a loop with all the other attributes. I am not sure if i am doing the right thing so here is my attempt

Here is the XML file:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="sample.xsd">

    <foo>
        <subfoo id="123">Foo 1</subfoo>
        <subfoo id="345">Foo 2</subfoo>
        <subfoo id="678">Foo 3</subfoo>
    </foo>

    <bar id="U123">
        <subbar>Hello World</subbar>
    </bar>

    <bar id="345">
        <subbar>Hello Other World</subbar>
    </bar>

    <bar id="912">
        <subbar>Hello 3rd World</subbar>
    </bar>

</root>
```

Here is the XSLT file:

```
  <xsl:template match="root">

            <xsl:variable name="subfoo" select="root/foo/subfoo"/>
            <xsl:variable name="subbar" select="root/bar"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$subfoo">
                <xsl:variable name="subfooID" select="./@id"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$subbar">
                    <xsl:if test="$subfooID = ./@id">
                        <xsl:if test="./@id[current()] = @id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="subfoo"/> Matches <xsl:value-of select="subbar"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>
```

And if the two ID's were matched an output should say something like

```
Foo 1 Matches Hello World
Foo 2 Matches Hello Other World
```

Can someone help me find what am i missing here?
Regards.

Comment: Why would `U123` match `123`?

Comment: In addition to all the other errors pointed out, `@id[current()]` selects id if current() exists, and current() always does exist, so the predicate is pointless. I suspect you meant `current()/@id`. You seem to be relying on guesswork rather than an understanding of the language spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply define a key for the cross-reference and then process the elements for which there is a cross-reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:key name="bar" match="bar" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="foo/subfoo[key('bar', @id)]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="subfoo">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' matches ', key('bar', @id)/subbar, '&#10;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzo

In your attempt you have a lots of wrong paths as you don't seem to be aware that an `xsl:template` or `xsl:for-each` changes the context so you would need to change e.g. `select="root/foo/subfoo"` to `select="foo/subfoo"`.